# Laravel Validation: bail rule not working

Tags: php, laravel, validation

According to [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#rule-bail), `bail` rule should stop running validation rules after first validation failure.

I have a file outside `App\Http\*` namespace with the following code in it:

```
if(Validator::make($params, [
    'email' => 'bail|required|email|max:60|exists:customers,email',
    'password' => 'required|max:60|string',
    'password' => new CustomerCheckPassword($params['email']),
]) -> fails())
    throw new Exception('message here');
```

Works like a charm, except `bail` rule from `email` attribute does not stop the validation when `$params['email']` is not contained by `customers.email`, and goes on to `password` as well. Do you have any ideas or elegant workarounds for this issue?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In a different section of the same docs page (it won't link directly to it), it explains that `bail` only applies to the current attribute. So for instance, if `email` is missing, it will not check anything after `required`, but `password` is a new attribute so it will validate it as normal.

> Sometimes you may wish to stop running validation rules on an attribute after the first validation failure. To do so, assign the bail rule to the attribute:

One way to accomplish this would be to use the `sometimes` method

```php
Validator::make($params, [
    'email' => 'bail|required|email|max:60|exists:customers,email',
    'password' => 'required|max:60|string',
])->sometimes('password', new CustomerCheckPassword($params['email']), function ($input) {
    // Check input to decide if rule should execute
});
```

Comment: Many thanks for answer! Do you know an elegant solution for preventing other attributes from being checked after first fail?

Comment: I'm not sure since I'm not familiar with your use case, and why you need to stop after the first error. If you're trying to limit your errors to 1, you could do `$validator = Validator::make(...)` then check `if ($validator->fails()) {` and use the first error like this: `$error = $validator->errors()->first()`. But I'm not sure thats what you're looking for.

Comment: `CustomerCheckPassword` requires a valid email, one that exists in table, otherwise it throws exception. I could check again if email exists from within rule and prevent the exception, but I'm enthralled that this could be accomplished in an easier way.

Comment: I think I see what you're going for. I don't know of a way to do it in quite as terse of a syntax as you're looking for unfortunately. The only way I can think to do it without checking inside of `CustomerCheckPassword` is to use the [`sometimes` function](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#conditionally-adding-rules) (under the 'Complex Conditional Validation' heading) to add the rule only if the email is present. This wouldn't save you any lines of code, but would take care of all the logic inside the validator.

Comment: Thanks for reply! This solves the problem. Please update answer to contain this information for further reference :)